# Appending values to an array for every iteration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to store the indices inside my test array inside two other arrays.

```
train_idx = np.zeros(3,dtype='object')
test_dx = np.zeros(3,dtype='object')

array = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
test = np.array(np.array_split(array, k))
[array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0]) array([1, 1, 1, 0]) array([1, 0, 0, 1])]
```

The arrays in test, i am trying to store each array inside a different array (train_index and test_index).

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    test_index = test[i]
    for j in range(len(test)):
        if i == j:
            continue
        train_index = test[j]
```

The issue with this, is that it's storing the last values for both arrays train_index and test_index

```
print(train_index)
print(test_index)

[1 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 1]
```

Whereas the full output can be see below:

```
[1 0 0 1 0]
[1 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 1]

[1 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 1 0]
[1 0 0 1]

[1 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 1 0]
[1 1 1 0]
```

What i want to do in-fact is append these values into their respective arrays, the output i'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
test_index = [[1 0 0 1 0], [1 1 1 0], [1 0 0 1]]
train_index = [[[1 1 1 0], [1 0 0 1]], [[1 1 1 0], [1 0 0 1]],  [[1 0 0 1], [1 1 1 0]]]
```

Comment: The fact that `np.array_split(array, k)` produces a list is intentional.  In general the elements will differ in size.  If they were the same size, it would faster to just reshape the array.  Object dtype arrays are much like lists, and few if any advantages.  And since you index with `test[i]` you actually loose performance by making `test` an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define test_index and train_index as empty list:

```
test_index = []
```

Then use append method:

```
test_index.append(test[i])
```

Comment: That's not possible, notice that test array is an array of arrays

Comment: So you want it to be a numpy array?

Comment: you can always use `test_index_np = np.array(test_index)` to convert it to a np array.